# I have my mac serving an application on port 80 that I can access within the network, how can I prevent it from sleeping?

Tags: network, sleep-wake

I have my mac serving an application on port 80 and I can access it from another device just fine, but only when the screen is on, when I close the lid I can no longer access this. These are my power settings:

[image]

Is there anything else I need to change?

Comment: Your Energy Saver status as displayed here shouldn't let your screen go to sleep and shouldn't let your system go to sleep if you are on your power adapter. If you are on battery, you should switch to the battery settings and check.

Comment: When the screen of the Mac is off, are you able to `ping` it from the client computer?

Comment: The screen doesn't need to be on for the Mac to keep running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Lid Open

Your Mac will [sleep if you close the lid](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/347580/does-prevent-computer-from-sleeping-remain-in-effect-even-if-i-close-the-lid?rq=1).

You need to leave your MacBook lid open for the server to keep responding to requests.

You can set the **display** to sleep after a period of idle time; this will not affect the server. Only the computer needs to remain awake.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the caffeinate utility from the terminal.
To access the terminal, 
Cmd+Space(Spotlight), then search for Terminal and press Enter.
Now, in the terminal type: 
caffeinate -t 3600 
3600 being the number of seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The computer will go to sleep when you close the lid -- unless:

1) You have a mouse/keyboard and display (or virtual display adapter) connected.

OR

2) You install software that allow the system to stay awake even with the lid closed. Some suggested pieces of software from various articles include: [Amphetamine](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/amphetamine/id937984704?mt=12), [Caffinated](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/caffeinated-anti-sleep-app/id1362171212?mt=12).
Give one or a few of them a try and see which one works best for you.